# Backup of "Leavers" network directory

Tags: backup, archiving

I want to create a backup of a Leavers network home directory.

I've generally done this before by just creating an iso with genisoimage and then burning it.

However, it seems that the latest users have > 10G in their files.  For archival purposes, I want to be able to burn these to multiple DVDs.

How do I create these DVD iso images (I know it's got something to do with tar and stream-media-size, and then how do I restore them if I need them again?

Using Debian

Answer (score 4):

I'd use either [rar](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rar) or one of those cheapo portable hard disks, they cost nothing these days and will save you a lot of time and effort.

Comment: Rar != Free, and it has to be to optical media. Policy.

Comment: You're seriously downvoting me because you want something for free yet at no point mention that requirement in your question - how is that wrong? also I point out another perfectly viable solution on top of my otherwise correct answer and that's somehow offensive to you as well - you're a little hard to please.

Comment: You *could* use 7zip (http://www.7-zip.org/) with this you can configure it to split at XYZ size then burn each segment to a disk (Downside is that you NEED all the segments to extract the contents)

Comment: Actually, no - my post says it's using Debian - it also says that it needs to be done to DVD.

Comment: rar is available for linux - though not free. Also 'want' != 'need'.

Comment: @Mez, unless you're getting the expensive "Archival Grade" DVDs, they go bad after ~10 years (more or less depending on environment). Burnt CD/DVD is generally a terrible way to archive data. I used to use rar, then found xz (LZMA compression ripped from 7Zip), paq also gets better compression, but takes ages.

Comment: @Chris - yes, we are using the expensive ones... and It's only a 3 year retention, IIRC

Answer (score 2):

assuming you're using linux, tar has an option for multivolume archives - i'll link the [appropriate page](http://www.gnu.org/software/tar/manual/html_section/Using-Multiple-Tapes.html) since there's a fair degree of complxity involved . Of course, if you lose one archive, you may not be able to extract the whole archive.

Alternately, another approach would be to split the directory into smaller directories, and taring and burning them - i belive [multicd](http://danborn.net/multiCD/) might work (its in the debian repo) for that - it'll split, tar and burn the dvd at one shot.  If you can install additional software this is likely the easier solution after initial setup.

Comment: I've already researched multicd and dar... Look good - but seem to want to write to weird file format - or to write directly to a burner.. I wonder if I can get a virtual burner setup that writes to isos.....